# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: problem

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title' => 'string|required',
        'summary' => 'string|nullable',
        'is_parent' => 'sometimes|in:1',
        'parent_id' => 'nullable',
        'status' => 'nullable|in:active,inactive'
    ]);
    $data=$request->all();
    $slug=Str::slug($request->title);
    $count=Category::where('slug',$slug)->count();
    if($count>0){
        $slug=$slug.'-'.date('ymdis').'-'.rand(0,999);
    }
    $data['slug']=$slug;
    // return $slug;
    $status=Category::create($data);
    if($status){
        request()->session()->flash('success','Kategori başarıyla eklendi');
    }
    else{
        request()->session()->flash('error','Kategori eklenirken hata oluştu');
    }
    return redirect()->route('category.index');

}
```

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'active' for column `kintshop`.`categories`.`parent_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `categories` (`title`, `summary`, `is_parent`, `parent_id`, `photo`, `status`, `slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dsadasd,

dsadasdas

, 1, active, /storage/photos/1/category1.png, active, dsadasd, 2021-06-04 13:09:04, 2021-06-04 13:09:04))

Here is my schema

```
    **Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_parent')->default(true);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->enum('status',['active','inactive'])->default('active');
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('SET NULL');
        $table->mediumText('summary')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });**
```

Comment: dd($data) and show what you get and also post migration file or table structure

Answer (score 0):

Error is clear .`Request` contain `parent_id` value `active` but `migration` file says `parent_id` is `foreign key` you must pass accurate value to create method.

`parent_id` data type is `Big Integer`

See your `$request->all()` data

```
 [▼ "_token" => "LrDekkz85cys4ZFx4vCFmy0VPHwFCh1u7aPIcEqq"

 "title" => "dsadasd" 
 "summary" => "<p>dsadasdas</p>" 
 "files" => null
 "is_parent" => "1" 
 "parent_id" => "active" 
 "photo" => "/storage/photos/1/category1.png"
 "status" => "active" ]
```

So better update validation rule for `parent_id` contain only integer

Answer (score 0):

Table column 'parent_id' is bigInteger but you have 'active' (string) in your request, so, change data type on DB or update validation rules.

TIP: don't use '$request->all()', is not safe.. you can use instead '$request->only('title', 'summary', 'status' .....)'. This is a safe practice to retrieve params from request

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'title' => 'string|required',
        'summary' => 'string|nullable',
        'is_parent' => 'sometimes|in:1',
        'parent_id' => 'nullable',
        'status' => 'nullable|in:active,inactive'
]);
```

This is wrong...$this->validate([]) accept the rules first as argument, not the request. Maybe you must do

```
$request->validate([
        'title' => 'string|required',
        'summary' => 'string|nullable',
        'is_parent' => 'sometimes|in:1',
        'parent_id' => 'nullable',
        'status' => 'nullable|in:active,inactive'
]);
```

or

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(),[rules]);
```